# How to fix "Error C2371 'time_t': redefinition; different basic types" in visual studio 2019?

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am beginner in using pthread header. I tried a sample of code in tutorial but it gave an error refer to TimLib.h library. I didn't include this header but it seems this header called in pthread.h. I will appreciate if you can guide me.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define NUM_THREADS     5

void* PrintHello(void* threadid)
{
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;
    printf("Hello World! It's me, thread #%ld!\n", tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long t;
    for (t = 0; t < NUM_THREADS; t++) {
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", t);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void*)t);
        if (rc) {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    /* Last thing that main() should do */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
**Error C2371    'time_t': redefinition; different basic types**    Project2    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.21.27702\include\TimeLib.h  21

Comment: Any reason to use pthreads in windows?

Comment: If you are using VS2019, you should use `std::thread` from `<thread>` instead of `pthread`s.

Comment: This looks like C, not C++.

Comment: I think `time_t` can have different sizes because the 32 bit version clips in the forseable future. Likely a conflict with what the pthreads lib assumes which may use it to implement delays. Another good reason to use c++ `std::thread`.